# In app billing debugging - uploading apk multiple times

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm currently writing my in-app-billing activity.

With every change i'm making, i need to upload the new apk to ther developer console(Beta) and wait several hours so i can test the new changes.
If god forbid i make a slight mistake i will need to correct int and wait several more hours till i can test the changes.

Testing the app in debug mode wont allow me any connection with google play starting with the IabHelper.

There has got to be a better way for testing that,
thank you.

Comment: [Not that I know of](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#draft_apps). You can try [static responses](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static) if that falls under something you still need to test.

Comment: You just need to upload the apk once. You can make changes, create a release apk and install on the device to test without the need to upload to dev console

Comment: then what is the need for uploading the apk? can i just upload a random apk? what does the developer console gets from it?